# Make list of list from specific str

Tags: python, list

I have a big list and looks like:

```
a=["cos","3","4","5","cos1","4","5","cos2","1"]
```

I would like create a list of list similar to:

```
a=[["cos","3","4","5"],["cos1","4","5"],["cos2","1"]]
```

I tried

```
sub=[]
for i,y in enumerate(a):
     if "cos" in y:
         sub.append([y])
         continue
```

It didn't work. Could you help me?

Comment: Please describe _how_ "it doesn't work". Being able to identify how your code falls short is an important first step to fixing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close to getting what you want. As it stands, you only create a new sub-list if `"cos"` is a part of the string you're currently looking at. What about when `"cos"` *isn't* in that string?

Right now, you just ignore this case. However, you want to *add this element* to the sub-list that you previously appended to `sub`. You can access the sub-list as `sub[-1]` because it's the last element of `sub`, and then append to it.

```
sub=[]
for y in a:
     if "cos" in y:
         sub.append([y])
     else:
         sub[-1].append(y)
```

Which gives

```
sub =  [['cos', '3', '4', '5'], ['cos1', '4', '5'], ['cos2', '1']]
```

I removed the unnecessary `enumerate()` and `continue`.

This assumes that the first element of `a` contains `"cos"`, so that `sub[-1]` will always exist when that line is executed. Handling the error when this isn't the case is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Watch for the occurrences of the `'cos'`. If you encounter numbers, you just add them to the temporary list. When you encounter the name `'cos'`, you should add the temp list(your sublist) to the result list Also create a new temp list which starts with the item has `'cos'`.

But there is an exception in the first iteration, you don't want to add empty list to the result(because you encounter `'cos'` but the temp is empty). So `if temp:` is for that.

If you do not want this extra *if condition*, and if your list begins with `'cos'`, you can have `temp = [a[0]]` at the beginning and then iterate through the rest of the items.

```
a = ["cos", "3", "4", "5", "cos1", "4", "5", "cos2", "1"]

res = []
temp = []
for item in a:
    if not item.startswith('cos'):
        temp.append(item)
    else:
        if temp:
            res.append(temp)
        temp = [item]

if temp:
    res.append(temp)
print(res)
```

output:

```
[['cos', '3', '4', '5'], ['cos1', '4', '5'], ['cos2', '1']]
```